# Обработка больших файлов

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Как грамотно использовать много-поточность что бы обрабатывать большие текстовые документы. Допустим у меня есть документ .txt в котором каждый символ `4` нужно заменить на `четыре` или `D` на `Д` и т.д. т.к. файлы очень большие то обработка такого числа символов(от 10 000 до 1 000 000) затягивается надолго. Использовать много поточность или как то иначе сократить время обработки?

Читаем файл :

```
string document = File.ReadAllText(Path);
string[] Mass = document.Split(' ');
```

далее в цикле обрабатываем каждый элемент массива `Mass`

UPD. Несмотря на решение, предложенное уважаемым @Vlad, некоторые файлы по прежнему обрабатываются очень медленно, что вновь натолкнуло меня на мысль о много поточной обработке. Разделить весь масиив слов на небольшие части и обрабатывать их - каждую часть в своем Thread и записывать во временный файл. 
Код :

```
        string allfile = File.ReadAllText(Path);
        string[] mass = allfile.Split(' ');
        double parts = 0;

        if (mass.Length > 200000)
        {
            parts = mass.Length / 200000;
            parts = Math.Round(parts);
            for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++)
            {
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    string empty = "";
                    for (int j = 0; j < 200000; j++)
                    {
                        empty += mass[(j + i * 200000)] + ' ';
                    }
                    var result = ProcessLine(empty);
                    File.WriteAllText("Temp_file" + i.ToString() + ".txt", result);
                    MessageBox.Show("Part Sucsess Rewrite");
                }).Start();
            }
        }
```

Ошибка -> индекс за передела ми границы диапазона. Как исправить ?

Comment: А как вы обрабатываете файл? Дайте пример кода.

Comment: попробуйте начать с профайлинга, чтобы понять где тратиться больше всего времени...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы делаете очень неоптимально: чтение всего файла в память и разбиение на строки создаёт много ненужных объектов, и нагружает память.

Попробуйте читать файл через `File.ReadLines` (ни в коем случае не через `ReadAllLines`!), обрабатывать построчно и записывать построчно в новый файл.

Например:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    "newfile",
    File.ReadLines("oldfile").Select(ProcessLine));
```

с функцией

```
string ProcessLine(string s)
{
    // обрабатываем одну строку и возвращаем результат 
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется посимвольная обработка будет еще быстрее. Буферизация наверняка та же самая и никаких строк делать не надо.

Comment: @avp: Вы правы, но это сложнее, т. к. наверняка придётся ещё и держать текущее состояние (пример: если нужно в строке убрать символы после `//`). Поэтому я бы начал с просто построчной обработки, и переходил к посимвольной только при необходимости.

Comment: На самом деле, если формат достаточно общий (скажем, JSON), то программы будут почти одинакового размера (и я даже не знаю, какая получится короче)

Comment: @avp: Я бы не обрабатывал JSON ничем, кроме парсера (формат сложный, баги в самописном парсер неизбежны), так что если данные реально не текст, а высокоуровневый формат, лучше бы об этом сказать в вопросе.

Comment: И я о том же. Если формат не примитивный, то нужен полноценный парсер (ну, и грамматика все равно будет сводится к символам). Только совсем что-то простое (и обязательно "строкоориентированное") может оказаться удобнее программировать читая строки, а не отдельные символы.

Comment: @avp: Я имел в виду именно чистый текстовый формат, он как раз строкоориентирован.

Comment: @VladD такое решение действительно заметно быстрее. Но все еще долго возится, когда число символов подлежащих изменению находится на уровне 70-80 %

Comment: @VladD StringBuilser совместно с вашим решением дали именно тот результат, который был нужен.!

Comment: @Сергей: Вот и отлично! Да, строки лучше обрабатывать при помощи StringBuilder.

Answer (score -1):

Во первых, используйте асинхронный доступ к файлам, чтобы высвобождать потоки обратно в пул и занять их другой работой, при активации IO потока.

Во вторых, прочитав содержимое, используйте Task.Parallel.Library для параллельного поиска в строках по файлу. (Parallel.ForEach)

Дальше, асинхронная запись целого файла.